# Flask with docker network: Flask doesn't support multiple network interfaces?

Tags: python, docker, flask, nic, docker-network

I'm trying to use flask in a docker container but it seems to have a multiple nic problem.

That flask container has two docker networks. One is bridge and the other one is overlay. Flask responses when I access to the bridge IP(from outside client or docker host). but it won't response when I access to the overlay network's IP(from other containers which are in the same overlay network).

app.py

```
`app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=80)`
```

docker-compose

```
ports: "5000:80"
net: "my-overlay-network"
command: "python app.py"
```

container's IP

```
root@flask:/app# ip a
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet 172.30.0.16/16 scope global eth0      <=== overlay IP
    inet 172.18.0.12/16 scope global eth1      <=== bridge IP
```

Access URL

- from outside client (works)

  - http://my-docker-host:5000/
- from docker host (works)

  - http://172.18.0.12/
- from other overlay network containers (doesn't work)

  - http://172.30.0.16/
  - fyi: These containers is in the same network because they can get flask's ip with nslookup.

Environment

- docker 1.11.1
- python 3.5.1
- flask 0.11

Comment: Can you ping between the containers over the overlay network?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Ping to the flask container from other containers in the overlay network does not work. BUT nslookup(to 127.0.0.11) works. It means they are in the same network. I'm wordering why flask is rejecting ping.

Comment: I would look into your local routing and firewall rules. `netstat -nr` and `sudo iptables -vS` on each node.

Comment: @BMitch My all containers are in the same docker host and the only one overlay network so that there is no firewall. Here is `netstart -nr` result of ping container.

`# netstat -nr     
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
`
ping to other containers like `ping 172.30.0.15` works.

Comment: @BMitch FYI, it works if I use flask with nginx and uwsgi. Only flask web server doesn't works. So that I doubt flask's nic problem.